# ¿Cómo se denomina a un invento extremadamente complejo para resolver algo sencillo?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

Estoy buscando en español la palabra que denomina un invento muy complejo y aparatoso que resuelve algo muy sencillo (lo que lo hace inútil). Creo que hay un concurso internacional para estos tipos de inventos.

Comment: En inglés está la Rube Goldberg machine, no sé si funciona en español.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quizás la palabra que busca es [**alambicado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1RcPEwY):

> 2. adj. **Complicado, rebuscado.** *Razonamiento, concepto alambicado*.

Para el concepto, la denominación es [**Máquina de Rube Goldberg**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Rube_Goldberg) aunque en España se utiliza más la expresión [**Invento del TBO**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_grandes_inventos_del_TBO) debido a la enorme popularidad que tuvo la sección de ese nombre del semanario TBO.

> La sección estaba presentada por un personaje ficticio, el profesor Franz de Copenhague.
> Algunos de los ingeniosos inventos del TBO fueron:
>
> ```
> Dispositivo para hacer vino con zapatos viejos (Nit)
> Procedimiento para descargar mercancías con jirafa (Nit)
> Coche salta-vallas (Nit)
> Aparato limpia-narices (Nit)
> Huevos con cáscara de cristal (Benejam)
> Melones cuadrados (Benejam)
> Sombrero-jaula (Tur)
> Dispositivo anti-cabello en la sopa (Sabatés)
> Artilugio para brindar en mesas grandes (Sabatés)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **La popularidad de esta sección llegó a quedar hasta en el lenguaje coloquial, con la frase "es un invento del TBO" para tachar a una idea de estrafalaria o absurda.**
> ...

[**Aquí**](https://web.archive.org/web/20111126053611/http://www.ciberniz.com/profesorfranz.htm) aclaran (para los que no los hayan conocido) que (énfasis mío):

> "Los grandes inventos" del Profesor Franz de Copenhague se movieron en dos planos humorísticos: **el de la simple exageración de máquinas complicadas para obtener resultados muy simples**, y el de la crítica disimulada a la coyuntura española; no hay que olvidar que en las décadas que florecían los "Grandes inventos" la sociedad, para atender necesidades o apetencias había tenido que inventar cosas casi tan sorprendentes como las del TBO...

Imágenes de algunos de estos inventos:

- [**Dispositivo para secar las "gotas" que caen de la nariz**](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-5mNOWzhvrMg/T2AIxdTo5MI/AAAAAAAAD6Q/aDJw9GprU-4/s640/TBO_Grandes_inventos.jpg)
- [**Máquina para cortar la punta de los cigarros**](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vzed8M6JN7k/VtTF6untl6I/AAAAAAAACs0/tL7fWIOiOBM/s640/tareaTBO.jpg)
- [**Máquina que ahorra el esfuerzo de llamar al timbre de una casa**](https://ixquick-proxy.com/do/spg/show_picture.pl?l=espanol&rais=1&oiu=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F14%2F1f%2Ff7%2F141ff71972b7a3867fe4520eb4d98770.jpg&sp=1fd2080fa6b788cfb9e4a79577bf49d2)

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Gracias.